# The best way to integrate multiple languages without reloading the page

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic

I am looking for an efficient way to integrate multiple languages in a webpage without reloading the whole site. From time to time you should also can add more languages easily.
Furthermore I want to set the language dynamically by geo locating the users ip.

I have heard of ajax, but I am pretty new to it and I don't know if it's the best way or not. Before endless searching in google I just wanted to ask you guys if you could give me a hint.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, AJAX is used to make the request to the server without reloading the whole page.. If you want to pass/get the information from/to the server without reloading the whole page, AJAX is the best way to do it..

Comment: You can find an AJAX tutorial here.. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/.... and AJAX in JQuery here.... http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate multiple languages in a webpage"? Do you want to change languages in front of the user, or you want to have a website in multiple languages and display one of them depending on user's preference?

Comment: I want to display a specific language depending on user's preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say what the best way is, depends on your app really. a simple way would be to use jquery to replace the text dynamically on language selection by user.

You could store a language file like:

```
var strings = {
    english: {
        hello: "Hello",
        world: "World"
    },
    french: {
        hello: "Bonjour",
        world: "blah.."
    }
}
```

Then use a function to update the strings:

```
var strLang = "english";

// update selected language   
function localizeStrings(strLang) {
    $(strings[strLang]).each(function(key, lang){
        $.each(lang, function(id, string) {
            $("#"+id).html(string);
        });
    });
}
```

and give each html entity an id

```
<a id="hello" class="button"></a>
<a id="world" class="button"></a>
```

here is a fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xrbs2mga/